# Removing white-spaces / empty values from a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm developing a word counting application and I'm using following code to load words to an array.

```
$str = ' Some string is here     ...  Another string.. ';
$str = trim($str);
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str);
$str_array = explode(" ", $str);
$str_array = array_filter($str_array);
```

But the issue is I'm getting empty values in my array like follows.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Word1
    [1] => Word2
    [2] => Word3
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
)
```

I've tried `array_filter($str_array)` and more stackoverflow answers. But I was failed to get this done. Can some one please help me to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Well, I'm not going to answer the actual question, but you can change your regex to `(\w+)` to extract words. It'd be more efficient.

Comment: @OP: Testing out the string you have provided works fine [here](https://eval.in/107980), you should either be able to reproduce this problem or give the exact string you are having trouble with.

Comment: This is the actual string `They provide a wide range of services that will help you with your Internet marketing concerns.     `

Comment: @OP: [This](https://eval.in/107986) is fine too. What's really the problem?

Comment: I'm phrasing a word document actually. $str contains phrased string. With var_dump, these empty values shows as `string '' (length=1)`

Comment: Sounds more like an issue of reading the word document than array trouble, how sure are you that the whole text is actually stored in  `$str`?

Comment: Seems like you are right. I have copied that text from the browser and pasted in to Notepad++ and got some special characters. see this >> http://s29.postimg.org/ju987r6ef/Capture.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue with `$str = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $str);`

[Source](http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/4224/)

```
        $str = strip_tags($str);
        $str = trim($str);
        $str = preg_replace('/ HYPERLINK "[^"]*" /', '', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $str);
```

Answer (score 6):

Trim the array elements using `trim` by `array_map` and finally do an `array_filter` using `strlen` as the call-back.

```
<?php
$arr=Array
(
    0 => 'Word1',
    1 => 'Word2',
    2 => 'Word3',
    3 => ' ',
    4 => '',
    5 => ''
);

$new_arr = array_filter(array_map('trim',$arr),'strlen');
print_r($new_arr);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/108000)

Comment: Can you `var_export` your array on your question before `array_filter` ? See the **demo**

Comment: using print_r(array_filter($str_array));

Comment: got  `531 => '',
  532 => '',
  533 => '',`

Comment: @madhushankarox, I had asked you to the update the `var_export` value of your array on the question without its hard to see what is inside your array.

Comment: Please see this >> http://s29.postimg.org/ju987r6ef/Capture.png  that string contains some special characters

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
 foreach ($array as $key=>$value) 
 { 
     if($value == '')
     {
       unset($array[$key]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: It's actually a word document. I'm phrasing a .doc and loading contents. But when I use var_export, these empty values returns as 531 => '', 532 => '', 533 => ''

Comment: Here is the text `They provide a wide range of services that will help you with your Internet marketing concerns.    `

Comment: its strange.. when I directly pass this string.. it doesnt give any blank value in the array..

Comment: try printing the array using `var_dump` and check if it returns length for that blank values...

Comment: My variable contains that string.

Comment: ohh ok.. its length should be `zero`.. Try putting `$value == ' '` **(single space)** in my given solution.. check wether it works or not..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48831/discussion-between-nishant-solanki-and-madhushankarox)

Comment: I think it is some type of special character or something which is coming from your doc file.... and yes try putting `header` in top of your page... like .. `header("Content-Type:text/plain");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = ' Some string is here     ...  Another string.. ';
$str = trim($str);
$str = str_replace('  ', ' ', $str); //replace two space to single space
$str_array = explode(" ", $str);
```